# How upcoming SameSite cookie changes could affect Magento or 3rd modules, possible issues?

Tags: magento2, security

On February, 4, Google is set to roll out a new Chrome update that promises a bunch of new features designed to make the browser faster and more secure — including a new approach to cookies.

The SameSite update will require website owners to explicitly state label the third-party cookies that can be used on other sites. Cookies without the proper labelling won’t work in the Chrome browser, which has 64% of the overall browser market, according to [Statcounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share).

Update:
Since I posted this question a lot of discussion has been done.

Currently the latest can be seen in the Magento 2 repo:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26377

Keep tunned!

Extra links:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-first-party-cookies-07
- https://www.troyhunt.com/promiscuous-cookies-and-their-impending-death-via-the-samesite-policy/